# How to replace .Id with a variable string value

Tags: javascript, variables, generics, field

I currently have the following in my Javascript code where Id is a field of an object:

```
this.recId = event.detail.row.Id;
```

I want to make the Id part generic something like

```
String a = 'Id';
this.recId = event.detail.row.a;
```

How do I achieve this in Javascipt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[ ]` instead.

```js
const obj = {
  id: "myObject"
}

const a = "id"

console.log(obj[a]);
```

In your example, it would be

```
this.recId = event.detail.row[a];
```

Comment: this.recId = event.detail.row[a]

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`this.recId = event.detail.row[a]` to get the desired result